# Multiple laravel project with 1 domain name without sub domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to have a multiple laravel project hosting in just 1 domain name. see example below. www.myproject.com (1st laravel project) then, www.myproject.com/otherproject (2nd laravel project)I dont have an access to add subdomain in domain name.

Comment: This is only few lines if done using `.htaccess`.

Test for `RewriteCond` to be a given directory and internally redirect to the associated directory's `public/index.php`

Answer (score 3):

You can add multiple projects to a single domain what you need to do is add you a public folder for each laravel project in a different folder and in index.php you need to change the path for the bootstrap.

for example:

if you have three projects of laravel then you need to save all projects in three different directory

Assuming you domain point at `/var/www/html`

1st project

```
    /var/www/laravel_project_1
```

2nd Project

```
    /var/www/laravel_project_2
```

3rd Project

```
    /var/www/laravel_project_3
```

Now you need to move all content in public folder present in project placed at

```
    /var/www/laravel_project_1/public
    /var/www/laravel_project_2/pubilc
    /var/www/laravel_project_3/public
```

and move them to domain point directory with new names

```
    /var/www/html/laravelProjet1
    /var/www/html/laravelProjet2
    /var/www/html/laravelProjet3
```

Now open index.php present in each folder and set a path to `bootstrap.php` at two places.

in first project folder at index.php 
    `/var/www/html/laravel_project_1/index.php`

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel_project_1/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel_project_1/bootstrap/app.php';
```

in second project folder at index.php `/var/www/html/laravel_project_2/index.php`

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel_project_2/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel_project_2/bootstrap/app.php';
```

in third project folder at index.php `/var/www/html/laravel_project_3/index.php`

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel_project_3/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel_project_3/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Now you can check the url stats working.

laravelprojectdomain.com/laravelProject1

laravelprojectdomain.com/laravelProject2

laravelprojectdomain.com/laravelProject3

Comment: will try it now sir, then will get back to you. btw thanks for answering my query :)

Comment: hi sir, is it possible that the first project is directly pointing to the domain name? and will not create a folder?

Comment: yes you can do that, for the first project you can move contents under public folder to directly in domain pointing folder(/var/www/html) and it will work at domain(laravelprojectdomain.com).